# How can I copy an element of vector<string> into a string?

Tags: c++, string, vector, copy

I've tried to copy like below.
I met crash, though.
Isn't it possible to use the assignment operator at this time?

```
std::vector<std::string> string_list;
std::string str;
string_list[0] = "abc";
str = string_list[0];
```

Comment: `push_back`/`emplace_back` or `resize` before.

Comment: Your vector isn’t initialized to a size, so therefore [0] does not exist yet. Instead, use the `push_back` that vector provides for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your vector is empty, therefore attempting to access the first element will result in a crash. You can initialize a vector like so:

```
std::vector<std::string> list = {"my string"};
std::string s = list[0];
```

Or if you prefer to dynamically grow the list you can do:

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
list.push_back("my string");
std::string s = list[0];
```

Comment: "Revenge" downvoting, too. Nice.

Comment: Do you have anything better to do than troll the comments section @LightnessRacesinOrbit.

Answer (score 3):

Your vector of strings `string_list`

```
std::vector<std::string> string_list;
```

is empty, i.e., it contains no element, no string at all, `size()` on that `std::vector` will return zero.

Then, in the statement:

```
string_list[0] = "abc";
```

You are writing to an element of the vector that does not exist and that results in undefined behavior (in your case, the program crashes).

---

Try initializing the vector in the following way instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> string_list(1);
```

This way, the vector `string_list` will contain a single empty string (i.e., a default constructed `std::string` object), which you can access using the `operator[]` (as you already did) on your vector of strings `string_list`:

```
string_list[0] = "abc";
```

By doing this, you are using the assignment operator of that empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Since, your vector is empty, you might get a crash when you attempt to access `string_list[0]` because you are trying to alter/access something that isn't there in the first place.

You can take care of it in two ways :

1. `std::vector<std::string> string_list(10)` Mention a non-zero size while declaring the vector( such as 10 ). That way the vector of strings will consists of 10 empty strings inside the vector.
2. Use `string_list.push_back("abc")`. This will dynamically allocate memory for your vector even if you don't explicitly declare the vector with a given size.

**Option 1 :**

```
std::vector<std::string> string_list(10);
string_list[0] = "abc"; // This is okay.
```

**Options 2 :**

```
std::vector<std::string> string_list; // Note that no size mentioned here.
string_list.push_back("abc"); //This is okay as well. :)
```